# Should I keep my listeners and layout variables in separate class

Tags: java, android, oop

Just want to ask the question again for myself. One can google the topic and many people point to the size of the parameter list of the resulting constructor is bad practice. Another point to make is that just keeping such a class in the activity/fragment is better practice.

Here is an example of a long parameter list.

```
public class ClusterClass {


private Context context;
private SlidingUpPanelLayout slidingUpPanelLayout;
private GoogleMap map;
private View rootView;
private ClusterManager<MyItem> mClusterManager;
private com.support.android.fetchpark.DefaultClusterRenderer mClusterRenderer;
private ShapeDrawable mColoredCircleBackground;
private float mDensity;


public ClusterClass(Context context,View rootView, GoogleMap map, SlidingUpPanelLayout slidingUpPanelLayout){

    this.context = context;
    this.slidingUpPanelLayout = slidingUpPanelLayout;
    this.map = map;
    this.rootView = rootView;

}
```

Here is a class that allowed me to remove a TON of code from my fragment. Its also great because its a UI element that I might want to use more than once.

```
public class MyFloatingActionMenu {

View rootView;
Context context;
private FloatingActionButton fab1,fab2,fab3;

public MyFloatingActionMenu(Context context, View rootView) {
    this.rootView = rootView;
    this.context = context;


}


public void setUpFam(){
    //get reference to activity layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);


    //Instantiate the FAM
    FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map_fragment_frame );
    View child = inflater.inflate(R.layout.floatingactionmenu, null);
    container.addView(child);


    //Configure FAM
    FloatingActionMenu menuLabelsRight = (FloatingActionMenu) rootView.findViewById(R.id.menu_labels_right);
    menuLabelsRight.hideMenuButton(false);
    menuLabelsRight.setClosedOnTouchOutside(true);
    menuLabelsRight.setIconAnimated(true);
    menuLabelsRight.showMenuButton(true);
    menuLabelsRight.setEnabled(true);

    //Store each FAB of the FAM
    fab1 = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map_fab1);
    fab2 = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map_fab2);
    fab3 = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map_fab3);

    //set listener for each FAB of the FAM
    fab1.setOnClickListener(fabClickListener);
    fab2.setOnClickListener(fabClickListener);
    fab3.setOnClickListener(fabClickListener);

}


private View.OnClickListener fabClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String text = "";

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.map_fab1:
                //do something

                break;
            case R.id.map_fab2:
                text = fab2.getLabelText();
                //fab2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            case R.id.map_fab3:
                text = fab3.getLabelText();
                // fab2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
        }
        Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};



  }
```

Please let me know what you think. While I only need one instance of these in my entire program, I have a FloatingActionMenu which I have also done the same thing with. Being able to instantiate it in both of my activities seems like a good OOP practice. What I dont like is that I now have almost 2x as many project files and I guess the constructors are long.

Comment: If you are looking for a code review, there is a [separate Stack Exchange site for that](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If you are seeking opinions, that is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Otherwise, please state what your specific question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big classes are ever bad practice, it's always recommend that you separate the functionalities in another classes. Leave the fragment to do only the simple functions like mapping the XML and add the listeners.

I think that you did correct when separate all the code from the fragment, because it will help you to better organize and maintain the code. :)

Just remember that

- Make sure your methods do only one thing.
- Make sure the class doesn't    have too many responsabilities.

> **Classes Should Be Small**
>
> The first rule of classes is that they should be small. The second
>   rule of classes is that they should be smaller than that. No, we’re
>   not going to repeat the exact same text from the Functions chapter.
>   But as with functions, smaller is the primary rule when it comes to
>   designing classes. As with functions, our immediate question is always
>   “How small?”
>
> The name of a class should describe what responsibilities it fulfills.
>   In fact, naming is probably the first way of helping determine class
>   size. If we cannot derive a concise name for a class, then it’s likely
>   too large. The more ambiguous the class name, the more likely it has
>   too many responsibilities. For example, class names including weasel
>   words like Processor or Manager or Super often hint at unfortunate
>   aggregation of responsibilities.